# EJS don't send values to mysql

Tags: mysql, ejs, crud

**This is my code for an update**

```
    controller.update = (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const newCostumer = req.body;
    req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        conn.query('UPDATE customer set ? WHERE id = ?' [newCostumer, id], (err, rows) =>{
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
};
```

**I put that console log to see the error and send me this**

```
  code: 'ER_EMPTY_QUERY',
  errno: 1065,
  sqlMessage: 'Query was empty',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql:
```

**and this is the form where I put the new values but it seems that not capture the values, its a mix of ejs and html**

```
<%- include ('partials/_header')  %>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="/update/<%= data.id %>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="name" value="<%= data.name %>" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="address" value="<%= data.address %>" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="phone" value="<%= data.phone %>" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Edit Customer
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<%- include ('partials/_footer')  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing comma on this line between the query string and the parameters array :

```
conn.query('UPDATE customer set ? WHERE id = ?', [newCostumer, id], (err, rows) =>{
```